# Configuring apache 2 virtual host - akamai problem

Tags: apache, dns, akamai

Normally I have no problems setting up Apache2 virtual hosts. However, in this case the domain is configured via Akamai rather than the normal DNS record, and apache is displaying the default site rather than the one I have configured for the required subdomain.

In other words, I have configured a virtual host test.domain.com, but Apache is displaying the default one when I go to http://test.domain.com/, and I guessing this is because Apache is not receiving the request from test.domain.com but from something else on the Akamai network.

How do I find out what the correct configuration of the virtual host should be?

Comment: More info: if I look at phptest for test.domain.com HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME just give the ip address of the server, and not test.domain.com as I would expect.

Comment: Can you extract all the _SERVER vars from phptest? Check that you do not have any settings in akamai deactivating HTTP/1.1, if you have only IP you'll need to work with IP based VirtualHosts and not Named based virtualhosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main domain (in this case test.domain.com) needs to be configured as a CNAME to the akamai network (test.domain.com.edgesuite.net), and then you need an origin hostname such as origin-test.domain.com.  Then you need to create an "Edge Hostname" on the akamai network portal and then a configuration on the HTTP network to answer for that digital property (test.domain.com).  Akamai can be configured to forward the requesting domain (test.domain.com) or the origin forward domain in the Host header (origin-test.domain.com).  either way you should setup your Apache Virtualhost to answer for both by doing

```
ServerName test.domain.com
ServerAlias origin-test.domain.com
```